# Mysql table type for Ethereum balance

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have balance in wei 1000000000000000000000. How can I store this int in mysql?

Bigint type is small for such numbers.

Comment: Perhaps `DECIMAL(65, 0)`?

Comment: the maximum number of digits (M) for DECIMAL is 65. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html